# Bicep deployments for CosmosDb SQL containers throws error on subsequent pipeline run

Tags: azure, arm, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-bicep

I am attempting to create a Bicep CosmosDb library based on the [ResourceModules](https://github.com/Azure/ResourceModules/) published my the MS Bicep team. I can successfully spin up the CosmosDb instance with Private Endpoints and on the first run the creation of the Sql container also works. On subsequent runs of the pipeline it fails on the Container with the below error message.

> ...{"Errors":["The input content is invalid -
> 'analyticalStorageTtl' is not a valid property in the current
> payload."]}...

I'm unsure why this is the case as I'm not passing that element to ARM and assume it's defaulted somewhere. Problem is if I do pass it with a valid value I still get the error. Anyone any idea how to get around this?

**EDIT:**

OK, this is a little strange and more than a little concerning. The issue I was getting on Friday has disappeared and the deployment is now working on subsequent runs. None of the Bicep files or configuration has changed. I'm a little concerned over the stability of Bicep as a direction for our infrastructure deployments now.

**Json (snippet)**

```
    "cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints":{
        "value":{
            "name": "cosdb-eun-h1s01-dev-iacsql123",
            "resourceGroup": "rg-eun-h1s01-dev-iac",
            "sqlDatabases": [
                {
                    "name": "mySqlDb",
                    "throughput": 400,
                    "containers": [
                        {
                          "conflictResolutionPolicy": {
                            "conflictResolutionPath": "/myId",
                            "mode": "LastWriterWins"
                          },
                          "defaultTtl": 1000,
                          "indexingPolicy": {
                            "automatic": true
                          },
                          "kind": "Hash",
                          "name": "container-001",
                          "paths": [
                            "/myPartitionKey"
                          ],
                          "throughput": 400,
                          "uniqueKeyPolicyKeys": [
                            {
                              "paths": [
                                "/firstName"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "paths": [
                                "/lastName"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                }
            ],
            "privateEndpoints": [
                {
                    "name": "pep-eun-h1s01-iac-cosdb-eun-iac123-sql",
                    "resourceGroup": "",
                    "subnet": {
                        "name": "snet-eun-h1s01-iac-storagepep",
                        "virtualNetworkResourceGroupName": "rg-eun-h1s01-dev-iac",
                        "virtualNetworkName": "vnet-eun-h1s01-iac-storage"
                    },
                    "groupIds": ["Sql"],
                    "ipConfigurations": [
                        {
                            "name": "default",
                            "properties": {
                                "memberName": "cosdb-eun-h1s01-dev-iacsql123",
                                "groupId": "Sql",
                                "privateIPAddress": "10.100.1.13"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "northeurope",
                            "properties": {
                                "memberName": "cosdb-eun-h1s01-dev-iacsql123-northeurope",
                                "groupId": "Sql",
                                "privateIPAddress": "10.100.1.14"
                            }
                        }
                        // ,
                        // {
                        //     "name": "westeurope",
                        //     "properties": {
                        //         "memberName": "cosdb-eun-h1s01-dev-iacsql123-westeurope",
                        //         "groupId": "Sql",
                        //         "privateIPAddress": "10.100.1.15"
                        //     }
                        // }                                                                                  
                    ],
                    "privateDns":{
                        "name" : "privatelink.documents.azure.com",
                        "resourceGroupName": ""
                    },                        
                    "tags": {
                        "Application": "Infrastructure as Code",
                        "CompanyCode": "V025",
                        "Critcality": "Category 1",
                        "Description": "CosmosDb private endpoint for Sql",
                        "Environment": "DEV",
                        "InternalOrder_CostCenter": "90020989",
                        "RemedyID": "CR999999",
                        "Version": "v1.0"
                    }                         
                }
            ],                
            "diagnosticSettings":{
                "storageAccount": {
                    "resourceGroup": "rg-eun-h1s01-dev-iac",
                    "accountName": "streundeviacdiag111"
                },
                "logAnalyticsWorkspace": {
                    "resourceGroup": "rg-euw-odpdev-shared-analytics",
                    "accountName": "law-euw-odpdev-7b08-default"
                }
            },                 
            "tags": {
                "Application": "Infrastructure as Code",
                "CompanyCode": "V025",
                "Critcality": "Category 1",
                "Description": "CosmosDb with NoSql for IaC",
                "Environment": "DEV",
                "InternalOrder_CostCenter": "90020989",
                "RemedyID": "CR999999",
                "Version": "v1.0"
            }                  
        }
    },
```

**Main.bicep (snippet)**

```
@description('The cosmos db with sql engine configuration from the environment json parameters file')
param cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints object


module cosmosDbSql 'br/Storage:cosmosdb:v0.1' = {
  name: 'cosmosDbSql-${cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.name}-${uniqueString(cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.name)}'
  scope: cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.resourceGroup != '' ? resourceGroup(cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.resourceGroup)  : resourceGroup()
  params: {
    name: cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.name
    defaultConsistencyLevel: contains(cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints, 'defaultConsistencyLevel') ? cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.defaultConsistencyLevel : 'Session'
    enableFreeTier: contains(cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints, 'enableFreeTier') ? cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.enableFreeTier : false
    capabilitiesToAdd:['EnableServerless']
    sqlDatabases: cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.sqlDatabases
    privateEndpoints: cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.privateEndpoints
    diagnosticStorageAccountId: resourceId(cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.diagnosticSettings.storageAccount.resourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.diagnosticSettings.storageAccount.accountName)
    diagnosticWorkspaceId: resourceId(cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.diagnosticSettings.logAnalyticsWorkspace.resourceGroup, 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.diagnosticSettings.logAnalyticsWorkspace.accountName)  
    tags: cosmosDbSqlwithPrivateEndpoints.tags
  }
}
```

**CosmosDb.bicep**

```
@description('Required. Name of the Database Account.')
param name string

@description('Optional. Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Required. An array of private endpoints objects')
param privateEndpoints array

@allowed([
  'Eventual'
  'ConsistentPrefix'
  'Session'
  'BoundedStaleness'
  'Strong'
])
@description('Optional. The default consistency level of the Cosmos DB account.')
param defaultConsistencyLevel string = 'Session'

@description('Optional. Flag to indicate whether Free Tier is enabled.')
param enableFreeTier bool = false

@description('Optional. SQL Databases configurations.')
param sqlDatabases array = []

@description('Optional. MongoDB Databases configurations.')
param mongodbDatabases array = []

@description('Optional. Gremlin Databases configurations.')
param gremlinDatabases array = []

@allowed([
  'EnableCassandra'
  'EnableTable'
  'EnableGremlin'
  'EnableMongo'
  'DisableRateLimitingResponses'
  'EnableServerless'
])
@description('Optional. List of Cosmos DB capabilities for the account.')
param capabilitiesToAdd array = []

@description('Optional. Resource ID of the diagnostic storage account.')
param diagnosticStorageAccountId string = ''

@description('Optional. Resource ID of the log analytics workspace.')
param diagnosticWorkspaceId string = ''

@description('Optional. Tags of the Database Account resource.')
param tags object = {}

//Default Values
var backupIntervalInMinutes = 240
var backupPolicyType = 'Continuous'
var backupPolicyContinuousTier = 'Continuous30Days'
var backupRetentionIntervalInHours = 8
var backupStorageRedundancy = 'Local'
var databaseAccountOfferType = 'Standard'
var automaticFailover = true
var maxIntervalInSeconds = 300
var maxStalenessPrefix = 100000
var serverVersion = '4.2'
var systemAssignedIdentity = true
var userAssignedIdentities = {}

var locations = contains(capabilitiesToAdd, 'EnableServerless') ? [
  {
    failoverPriority: 0
    locationName: 'North Europe'
    isZoneRedundant: false    
  }    
] : [
  {
    failoverPriority: 0
    locationName: 'North Europe'
    isZoneRedundant: false    
  }
  {
    failoverPriority: 1
    locationName: 'West Europe'
    isZoneRedundant: false    
  }
]

//Build diagnostics objects
var diagnosticLogsRetentionInDays = 365
var diagnosticLogCategoriesToEnable = ['allLogs']
var diagnosticMetricsToEnable = ['Requests']
var diagnosticSettingsName = 'diag-${name}-cosmos-log'

var diagnosticsLogsSpecified = [for category in filter(diagnosticLogCategoriesToEnable, item => item != 'allLogs'): {
  category: category
  enabled: true
  retentionPolicy: {
    enabled: true
    days: diagnosticLogsRetentionInDays
  }
}]

var diagnosticsLogs = contains(diagnosticLogCategoriesToEnable, 'allLogs') ? [
  {
    categoryGroup: 'allLogs'
    enabled: true
    retentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: diagnosticLogsRetentionInDays
    }
  }
] : diagnosticsLogsSpecified

var diagnosticsMetrics = [for metric in diagnosticMetricsToEnable: {
  category: metric
  timeGrain: null
  enabled: true
  retentionPolicy: {
    enabled: true
    days: diagnosticLogsRetentionInDays
  }
}]

var identityType = systemAssignedIdentity ? (!empty(userAssignedIdentities) ? 'SystemAssigned, UserAssigned' : 'SystemAssigned') : (!empty(userAssignedIdentities) ? 'UserAssigned' : 'None')

var identity = identityType != 'None' ? {
  type: identityType
  userAssignedIdentities: !empty(userAssignedIdentities) ? userAssignedIdentities : null
} : null

var consistencyPolicy = {
  Eventual: {
    defaultConsistencyLevel: 'Eventual'
  }
  ConsistentPrefix: {
    defaultConsistencyLevel: 'ConsistentPrefix'
  }
  Session: {
    defaultConsistencyLevel: 'Session'
  }
  BoundedStaleness: {
    defaultConsistencyLevel: 'BoundedStaleness'
    maxStalenessPrefix: maxStalenessPrefix
    maxIntervalInSeconds: maxIntervalInSeconds
  }
  Strong: {
    defaultConsistencyLevel: 'Strong'
  }
}

var databaseAccount_locations = [for location in locations: {
  failoverPriority: location.failoverPriority
  isZoneRedundant: location.isZoneRedundant
  locationName: location.locationName
}]

var kind = !empty(sqlDatabases) || !empty(gremlinDatabases) ? 'GlobalDocumentDB' : (!empty(mongodbDatabases) ? 'MongoDB' : 'Parse')

var capabilities = [for capability in capabilitiesToAdd: {
  name: capability
}]

var backupPolicy = backupPolicyType == 'Continuous' ? {
  type: backupPolicyType
  continuousModeProperties: {
    tier: backupPolicyContinuousTier
  }
} : {
  type: backupPolicyType
  periodicModeProperties: {
    backupIntervalInMinutes: backupIntervalInMinutes
    backupRetentionIntervalInHours: backupRetentionIntervalInHours
    backupStorageRedundancy: backupStorageRedundancy
  }
}

var databaseAccount_properties = union(
  {databaseAccountOfferType: databaseAccountOfferType },
  {networkAclBypass: 'AzureServices'}, 
  {publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'},
  ((!empty(sqlDatabases) || !empty(mongodbDatabases) || !empty(gremlinDatabases)) ? {
    // Common properties
    consistencyPolicy: consistencyPolicy[defaultConsistencyLevel]
    locations: databaseAccount_locations
    capabilities: capabilities
    enableFreeTier: enableFreeTier
    backupPolicy: backupPolicy
  } : {}), 
  (!empty(sqlDatabases) ? {
    // SQLDB properties
    enableAutomaticFailover: automaticFailover
  } : {}), 
  (!empty(mongodbDatabases) ? {
    // MongoDb properties
    apiProperties: {
      serverVersion: serverVersion
    }
  } : {})
  )


var enableDefaultTelemetry = true
resource defaultTelemetry 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments@2021-04-01' = if (enableDefaultTelemetry) {
  name: 'pid-47ed15a6-730a-4827-bcb4-0fd963ffbd82-${uniqueString(deployment().name, location)}'
  properties: {
    mode: 'Incremental'
    template: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      resources: []
    }
  }
}

resource databaseAccount 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2022-08-15' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  tags: tags
  identity: identity
  kind: kind
  properties: databaseAccount_properties
}

resource databaseAccount_diagnosticSettings 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticsettings@2021-05-01-preview' = if ((!empty(diagnosticStorageAccountId)) || (!empty(diagnosticWorkspaceId))) {
  name: !empty(diagnosticSettingsName) ? diagnosticSettingsName : '${name}-diagnosticSettings'
  properties: {
    storageAccountId: !empty(diagnosticStorageAccountId) ? diagnosticStorageAccountId : null
    workspaceId: !empty(diagnosticWorkspaceId) ? diagnosticWorkspaceId : null
    metrics: diagnosticsMetrics
    logs: diagnosticsLogs
  }
  scope: databaseAccount
}

module databaseAccount_sqlDatabases 'br/Storage:cosmosdb/sql:v0.1' = [for sqlDatabase in sqlDatabases: {
  name: '${uniqueString(deployment().name, location)}-sqldb-${sqlDatabase.name}'
  params: {
    databaseAccountName: databaseAccount.name
    name: sqlDatabase.name
    containers: contains(sqlDatabase, 'containers') ? sqlDatabase.containers : []
    throughput: contains(sqlDatabase, 'throughput') ? sqlDatabase.throughput : 400
    autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput: contains(sqlDatabase, 'autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput') ? sqlDatabase.autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput : -1
  }
}]

module databaseAccount_mongodbDatabases 'br/Storage:cosmosdb/mongo:v0.1' = [for mongodbDatabase in mongodbDatabases: {
  name: '${uniqueString(deployment().name, location)}-mongodb-${mongodbDatabase.name}'
  params: {
    databaseAccountName: databaseAccount.name
    name: mongodbDatabase.name
    collections: contains(mongodbDatabase, 'collections') ? mongodbDatabase.collections : []
  }
}]

module databaseAccount_gremlinDatabases 'br/Storage:cosmosdb/gremlin:v0.1' = [for gremlinDatabase in gremlinDatabases: {
  name: '${uniqueString(deployment().name, location)}-gremlin-${gremlinDatabase.name}'
  params: {
    databaseAccountName: databaseAccount.name
    name: gremlinDatabase.name
    graphs: contains(gremlinDatabase, 'graphs') ? gremlinDatabase.graphs : []
  }
}]

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Assign Private Endpoint to the Storage account sub resource type//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module privateEndpointsModule 'br/Network:privateendpoint:v0.1' = [for endpoint in privateEndpoints: {
  name: 'pep-${endpoint.name}-${uniqueString(endpoint.name, location)}'
  scope: endpoint.resourceGroup != '' ? resourceGroup(endpoint.resourceGroup)  : resourceGroup()
  params: {
    name: endpoint.name
    location: location
    serviceResourceId: databaseAccount.id
    subnetResourceId: resourceId(endpoint.subnet.virtualNetworkResourceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', endpoint.subnet.virtualNetworkName, endpoint.subnet.name)
    ipConfigurations: endpoint.ipConfigurations
    groupIds: endpoint.groupIds
    privateDnsZoneGroup: {
      name: endpoint.privateDns.name
      privateDNSResourceIds: [resourceId(endpoint.privateDns.resourceGroupName != '' ? endpoint.privateDns.resourceGroupName  : resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/', endpoint.privateDns.name)]
    }
    tags: endpoint.tags
  }
}]

@description('The name of the database account.')
output name string = databaseAccount.name

@description('The resource ID of the database account.')
output id string = databaseAccount.id

@description('The name of the resource group the database account was created in.')
output resourceGroupName string = resourceGroup().name

@description('The principal ID of the system assigned identity.')
output systemAssignedPrincipalId string = systemAssignedIdentity && contains(databaseAccount.identity, 'principalId') ? databaseAccount.identity.principalId : ''

@description('The location the resource was deployed into.')
output location string = databaseAccount.location
```

**CosmosSql.bicep**

```
@description('Conditional. The name of the parent Database Account. Required if the template is used in a standalone deployment.')
param databaseAccountName string

@description('Required. Name of the SQL database .')
param name string

@description('Optional. Array of containers to deploy in the SQL database.')
param containers array = []

@description('Optional. Request units per second. Will be set to null if autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput is used.')
param throughput int = 400

@description('Optional. Specifies the Autoscale settings and represents maximum throughput, the resource can scale up to.  The autoscale throughput should have valid throughput values between 1000 and 1000000 inclusive in increments of 1000. If value is set to -1, then the property will be set to null and autoscale will be disabled.')
param autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput int = -1

@description('Optional. Tags of the SQL database resource.')
param tags object = {}

@description('Optional. Enable telemetry via a Globally Unique Identifier (GUID).')
var enableDefaultTelemetry = true

resource defaultTelemetry 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments@2021-04-01' = if (enableDefaultTelemetry) {
  name: 'pid-47ed15a6-730a-4827-bcb4-0fd963ffbd82-${uniqueString(deployment().name)}'
  properties: {
    mode: 'Incremental'
    template: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      resources: []
    }
  }
}

resource databaseAccount 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2022-08-15' existing = {
  name: databaseAccountName
}

resource sqlDatabase 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases@2022-08-15' = {
  name: name
  parent: databaseAccount
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: name
    }
    options: contains(databaseAccount.properties.capabilities, { name: 'EnableServerless' }) ? null : {
      throughput: autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput == -1 ? throughput : null
      autoscaleSettings: autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput != -1 ? {
        maxThroughput: autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput
      } : null
    }
  }
}

module container 'br/Storage:cosmosdb/sql/containers:v0.1' = [for container in containers: {
  name: '${uniqueString(deployment().name, sqlDatabase.name)}-sqldb-${container.name}'
  params: {
    databaseAccountName: databaseAccountName
    sqlDatabaseName: name
    name: container.name
    autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput: contains(container, 'autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput') ? container.autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput : -1
    conflictResolutionPolicy: contains(container, 'conflictResolutionPolicy') ? container.conflictResolutionPolicy : {}
    defaultTtl: contains(container, 'defaultTtl') ? container.defaultTtl : -1
    indexingPolicy: contains(container, 'indexingPolicy') ? container.indexingPolicy : {}
    kind: contains(container, 'kind') ? container.kind : 'Hash'
    paths: contains(container, 'paths') ? container.paths : []
    throughput: contains(container, 'throughput') ? container.throughput : 400
    uniqueKeyPolicyKeys: contains(container, 'uniqueKeyPolicyKeys') ? container.uniqueKeyPolicyKeys : []
  }
}]

@description('The name of the SQL database.')
output name string = sqlDatabase.name

@description('The resource ID of the SQL database.')
output resourceId string = sqlDatabase.id

@description('The name of the resource group the SQL database was created in.')
output resourceGroupName string = resourceGroup().name
```

**CosmosSqlDbContainer.bicep**

```
@description('Required. The name of the parent Database Account. Required if the template is used in a standalone deployment.')
param databaseAccountName string

@description('Required. The name of the parent SQL Database. Required if the template is used in a standalone deployment.')
param sqlDatabaseName string

@description('Required. Name of the container.')
param name string

@description('Optional. The conflict resolution policy for the container. Conflicts and conflict resolution policies are applicable if the Azure Cosmos DB account is configured with multiple write regions.')
param conflictResolutionPolicy object = {}

@maxValue(2147483647)
@minValue(-1)
@description('Optional. Default time to live (in seconds). With Time to Live or TTL, Azure Cosmos DB provides the ability to delete items automatically from a container after a certain time period. If the value is set to "-1", it is equal to infinity, and items dont expire by default.')
param defaultTtl int = -1

@description('Optional. Request Units per second. Will be set to null if autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput is used.')
param throughput int = 400

@maxValue(1000000)
@description('Optional. Specifies the Autoscale settings and represents maximum throughput, the resource can scale up to. The autoscale throughput should have valid throughput values between 1000 and 1000000 inclusive in increments of 1000. If value is set to -1, then the property will be set to null and autoscale will be disabled.')
param autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput int = -1

@description('Optional. Tags of the SQL Database resource.')
param tags object = {}

@description('Optional. List of paths using which data within the container can be partitioned.')
param paths array = []

@description('Optional. Indexing policy of the container.')
param indexingPolicy object = {}

@description('Optional. The unique key policy configuration containing a list of unique keys that enforces uniqueness constraint on documents in the collection in the Azure Cosmos DB service.')
param uniqueKeyPolicyKeys array = []

@description('Optional. Indicates the kind of algorithm used for partitioning.')
@allowed([
  'Hash'
  'MultiHash'
  'Range'
])
param kind string = 'Hash'

var enableDefaultTelemetry = true
resource defaultTelemetry 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments@2021-04-01' = if (enableDefaultTelemetry) {
  name: 'pid-47ed15a6-730a-4827-bcb4-0fd963ffbd82-${uniqueString(deployment().name)}'
  properties: {
    mode: 'Incremental'
    template: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      resources: []
    }
  }
}

resource databaseAccount 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2022-08-15' existing = {
  name: databaseAccountName

  resource sqlDatabase 'sqlDatabases@2021-07-01-preview' existing = {
    name: sqlDatabaseName
  }
}

resource container 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2022-08-15' = {
  name: name
  parent: databaseAccount::sqlDatabase
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    resource: {
      conflictResolutionPolicy: conflictResolutionPolicy
      defaultTtl: defaultTtl
      id: name
      indexingPolicy: !empty(indexingPolicy) ? indexingPolicy : null
      partitionKey: {
        paths: paths
        kind: kind
      }
      uniqueKeyPolicy: !empty(uniqueKeyPolicyKeys) ? {
        uniqueKeys: uniqueKeyPolicyKeys
      } : null
    }
    options: contains(databaseAccount.properties.capabilities, { name: 'EnableServerless' }) ? null : {
      throughput: autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput == -1 ? throughput : null
      autoscaleSettings: autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput != -1 ? {
        maxThroughput: autoscaleSettingsMaxThroughput
      } : null
    }
  }
}

@description('The name of the container.')
output name string = container.name

@description('The resource ID of the container.')
output resourceId string = container.id

@description('The name of the resource group the container was created in.')
output resourceGroupName string = resourceGroup().name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually collection of Microsoft Employees that predominantly contribute to the modules referenced, not the Microsoft Bicep team.

I'd suggest raising an issue on the repository for that team to advise. https://github.com/Azure/ResourceModules/issues

The error you're receiving `analyticalStorageTtl is not a valid property` is likely because the underlying resource provider has changed and a bug has crept into the modules. Even though you're not using it, those modules generally take an approach of capturing every possible property option and then relaying to the underlying resource declaration. This approach does give flexibility, but also creates a larger error surface area - something that generally should be factored in when designing modules.

The project generally advises you use modules from a release, rather than the main branch... Perhaps this might also help you?

> Default path: To avoid disruptions, use distinct versions available
> through releases.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I will get the previous release and give that a go. Also, I had no idea that it wasn't a formal MS team developing the modules, seems kind of important if MS want Bicep to gain traction.

Comment: I think I would consider it a formal Microsoft team and project - but there is a difference between that and the actual Product/Engineering team.